# How to make correct View for tasks for each user?

Tags: 7, views

I have taxonomy vocabulary with departments. Different users have task's nodes.

I need View like this:

Department1   Task5_ForUser10
Department2
Department3
Department4   Task7_ForUser10
Department5

I've created View with taxonomy terms, Relationship with task's node and with Contextual filter "User ID from logged in user", but I see now only short variant:

Department1   Task5_ForUser10
Department4   Task7_ForUser10

How can I get View with full department list and tasks for each user?

Comment: It's a bit hard to say without knowing how departments & tasks relate to each other, what type of entities they are, and more details about the view settings, but it seems like your view is showing tasks or it is requiring the relationship between departments and tasks. It would need to be a view of departments, then having the relationship to the task that is not a required relationship. But then if you are showing only things where the task matches the current user then it won't show anything other than that. It seems complex and we would need all the information to answer properly.

Comment: Departments are taxonomy terms. Tasks are nodes with term reference field. Task nodes have Author as wanted user.

Comment: View relationship is set as bridge to the Content entity that is referencing Taxonomy term via field.

Comment: As a result - I've made all code in views tpl.php files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve above problem using [Views Field View](https://drupal.org/project/views_field_view) module..

Project page says

> This module allows you to embed a view as a field in a view. A new
>   field handler is made available, so this can also be used in area
>   (header/footer/empty) handlers as well as rows.

- Create a new view which accepts term id as argument and lists nodes related to that term
- Add Contextual Filter Author ID - Provide default value
- In your view add term id and select Exclude option
- In your view add above view as a field and read term id using token in settings.

[image]

See the result below

[image]